# What happened to Rhino Mocks' Arg<T>.Property

Tags: rhino-mocks

`Arg<T>.Property` is part of the documentation on inline constraints for Rhino Mocks v3.5, but I can't find it in v.3.6. What happened?

The documentation is here: http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#SimpleConstraints

and `Arg<T>.Property` is mentioned in the constraints reference table.

Comment: I also wonder what happened... and more specifically, what's the better alternative. You could perhaps use Arg<T>.Matches...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the documentation. When examining the `Rhino.Mocks.dll` (3.6.0.0) in the Object Browser I see that `Rhino.Mocks.Arg<T>` only offers the methods `Is` and `List` but not `Property`.

However `Rhino.Mocks.Constraints` contains the `Property` class. Using the "old" syntax you should be able to do the same:

AAA syntax (producing compile error):

```
myStub.Expect(x => x.MethodToCall(Arg<T>.Property.Value("PropertyName", myDesiredPropertyValue))).Result(myMockResult);
```

Old syntax (working):

```
myStub.Expect(x => x.MethodToCall(null)).Constraints(Property.Value("PropertyName", myDesiredPropertyValue)).Result(myMockResult);
```

The documentation says *"You're probably used to `IgnoreArguments()`, `Constraints()` and `RefOut()`. [...] It is encouraged to use only `Arg<T>`, it is more consistent and easier to understand, even if sometimes a little more to write."*

As Jeff Bridgman noted, you can also use `Arg<T>.Matches`:

```
myStub.Expect(x => x.MethodToCall(Arg<T>.Matches(m => m.PropertyName == myDesiredPropertyValue))).Result(myMockResult);
```

It has the advantage of being 'refactory safe', meaning that you can refactor the name of the property safely without the need to search for any 'magic strings'. It also meets the suggestion in the documentation to rather use `Arg<T>` instead of `Constraints()`.

Comment: Yep, I also ended up using the Arg<T>.Matches method due to its 'no magic strings attached' quality. Thanks for the answers.